# Modifying elements in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

In my html I want to get all elements with an attribute of "accesskey" and when I get those elements I want to add an attribute to modify them to underline them (sample below). I looked at the document.evaluate in [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) and I can use XPath to get all elements with an accesskey. However I read that I cannot modify the elements of an XPath. I would like to ask for guidance on what approaches I should possibly use to achieve this.

```
<label accesskey="L">Last Name</label>
```

becomes:

```
<label accesskey="L"><u>L</u>ast Name</label>
```

Comment: Difficult to understand why this is being done on the client rather than on the server. If it knows the access key, why can't it highlight it?

Comment: @RobG I am not an expert in web yet, if this can be done in the server could you refer me to some topics that I could study in order to know how that is done.

Comment: @user880772 yes CSS is an option. I'll take a look at attribute selector

Comment: @user880772 it depends on the letter specified in the accesskey. I looked at the css selector and I dont think it could do that. I believe it can only be done programatically or am I wrong? I'm still starting to study web so any suggestions that I could study is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use selectors with querySelectorAll() like

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('[accesskey]'),
  el, key;
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  el = els[i];
  key = el.getAttribute('accesskey');
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(key, '<u>' + key + '</u>')
}
```

```html
<label accesskey="L">Last Name</label>
```

Comment: I marked this as the answer but of course I researched on its performance and saw that querySelectorAll has performance issues. I am sharing this code solution that deals with the performance [issues] (http://ryanmorr.com/abstract-away-the-performance-faults-of-queryselectorall/)